# Selenium - Change IFrame and wait

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe

Our selenium tests have to switch between iFrames. We are using

`IWebdriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();`

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);`
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame1));`

The switching to DefaultContent always works. But the switching to frame1
works only sometimes.
Mostly we get an *OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element*
exception.
I'm not sure how this can happen because we are waiting to the IFrame to appear for 60 seconds.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code. I don't see enough code to suggest a fix.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.